# Ошибка при создании регистрации: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ...\registration.php on line 99

Tags: php, регистрация

```html
<?php 
         
          session_start();          
include ("bd.php");
if    (!empty($_SESSION['login']) and !empty($_SESSION['password']))
            {
            
            $login    = $_SESSION['login'];
            $password    = $_SESSION['password'];
            $result    = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id,avatar FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND    password='$password'"); 
            $myrow    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            }
            ?>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Главная    страница</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h2>Главная    страница</h2>          
           
<?php
            if    (!isset($myrow['avatar']) or $myrow['avatar']=='') {

            print    <<<HERE
            <form    action="testreg.php" method="post">
            
              <p>
                <label>Ваш логин:<br></label>
                <input    name="login" type="text" size="15"    maxlength="15"
            HERE;          
         
            if (isset($_COOKIE[login])) 
            {
           
            echo    ' value="'.$_COOKIE[login].'">';
            }          
 

print <<<HERE 
              </p>
           
              <p>
                <label>Ваш пароль:<br></label>
                <input    name="password" type="password" size="15"    maxlength="15"
            HERE;          
         
            if (isset($_COOKIE[password]))
            {
          
            echo    ' value="'.$_COOKIE[password].'">';
            }

                     
            print    <<<HERE
              </p>
              
              <p>
                <input name="save" type="checkbox"    value='1'> Запомнить меня.
              </p>          
<p>
            <input    type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти">
          
            <br>

            <a    href="reg.php">Зарегистрироваться</a> 
            </p></form>
            <br>
            Вы    вошли на сайт, как гость<br><a    href='#'>Эта    ссылка доступна только зарегистрированным пользователям</a>
            HERE;
            }          
else 
            {
    
           
print <<<HERE 


            Вы    вошли на сайт, как $_SESSION[login] (<a    href='exit.php'>выход</a>)<br>
                   
<a    href='http://tvpavlovsk.sk6.ru/'>Эта    ссылка доступна только зарегистрированным пользователям</a><br>

            Ваш    аватар:<br>
            <img    alt='$_SESSION[login]' src='$myrow[avatar]'> 
                
HERE;          

            }          
?>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При использовании строки с heredoc-синтаксисисом перед закрывающим идентификатором не должно быть отступа.

```
print    <<<HERE
      .....
HERE; 
// не должно быть отступа перед "HERE;"
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!